# compare topologically sorted list with the original list

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm, boost-graph

i have a vector of vertices from mygraph, and i topologically sort the vertices.

```
typedef typename boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, 
       boost::directedS,Vertex_t*> Graph_t;

typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Graph_t>::vertex_descriptor Vd_t;
Graph_t mygraph;
std::vector<Vd_t> v1; 
//initialize the vertices and get a copy of vertices in vector v1
//...
//and then i use

std::vector<Vd_t> v2;
boost::topological_sort(mygraph,std::back_inserter(v2));
```

to topologically sort the vertices 'in order'.
So what is the best way to compare v1 and v2 to test if my original vector of vertices(v1) was 'in order' or 'out of order'.

EDIT:
For example:
if vector v1 has vertices {A,  B,  C} and we have edges
(A,B)
(C,A)

so after topological sort I'll have in v2

{C, A, B}

There will be cases where i may not get a unique topological order, for example if i have 
(A,C) as the only edge, then v2 might end up with
{A , B , C} or {B , A , C}

Now i need to look into v1 and v2 to find out if both v1 and v2 represent the same order or not.

SECOND EDIT:
I tried an approach and it works for now, please tell me if this is a good approach or not.

```
template <typename Vertex_t>
void DepAnalyzer<Vertex_t>::CheckTotalOrder()
{
  //Vd_t is the vertex descriptor type
  typename std::vector<Vd_t> topo_order;
  typename std::vector<Vd_t>::iterator ordered_vertices_iter;

  //puts the topologically sorted vertices into topo_order
  DoTopologicalSort(topo_order);

  //will point to the vertices in the order they were inserted
  typename boost::graph_traits<Graph_t>::vertex_iterator vi, vi_end;
  std::unordered_map<Vertex_t*,int,std::hash<Vertex_t*>,
                      VertexEqual> orig_order_map, topo_order_map;  

  int i = 0;
  for(std::tie(vi, vi_end) = boost::vertices(depGraph); vi != vi_end; ++vi) {
    orig_order_map[depGraph[*vi]] = ++i;
    //std::cout<<depGraph[*vi]->get_identifier_str()<<"\n";
  }
  i = 0;
  //will point to the vertices in the topological order
  ordered_vertices_iter = topo_order.begin();
  for(;ordered_vertices_iter != topo_order.end(); ordered_vertices_iter++) {
    topo_order_map[depGraph[*ordered_vertices_iter]] = ++i;
    //std::cout<<depGraph[*ordered_vertices_iter]->get_identifier_str()<<"\n";
  }
  //checking the order now
  ordered_vertices_iter = topo_order.begin();
  for(;ordered_vertices_iter != topo_order.end(); ordered_vertices_iter++) {
    //if the vertex in topologically sorted list occurs before(w.r.t. position)
    //the macro in the original list of vertices, then it's okay
    if(orig_order_map[depGraph[*ordered_vertices_iter]] >
      topo_order_map[depGraph[*ordered_vertices_iter]]) {
      std::cerr << depGraph[*ordered_vertices_iter]->get_identifier_str() 
                << ": out of order\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If `v2` was already a copy of `v1`, the call `boost::topological_sort( mygraph, std::back_inserter(v2))` is guaranteed not to give the same result: `v2` will contain all of `v1` in the same order followed by the sorted version. (i.e. `v2.size()==2*v1.size()`) Also note that in many cases there is more than one valid topological sort for a given graph, so if they are not equal you will know that they are not the *same* topological sort, which is different from knowing that `v1` was not a *topological sort*.

Comment: sorry for the mistake... corrected now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So what is the best way to compare v1 and v2 to test if my original vector of vertices(v1) was 'in order' or 'out of order'.

Not comparing the vectors. The test is flawed in that if it succeeds (both vectors are the same) you will know that it was in order, but if it fails (vectors differ) you will not know whether it was out of order or if it was in a different order.

Consider the graph (imagine edges going down):

```
  A
 / \
B   C
 \ /
  D
```

The lists `{ A, B, C, D }` and `{ A, C, B, D }` are both in topological order, because there is no ordering constraint between `B` and `C`. If you had one of the options and the `boost::topological_sort` yielded the other variant you will not know whether you had an incorrect order or rather a different correct one.

It is probably better to write a simple algorithm that will check the order for *correctness* and reorder if needed.

Comment: yeah i understand the problem, that's why i asked if there is already a method to find out whether v1 and v2 are both in order or not. Should i resort to the naive O(n^2) method of comparing two vectors element by element or some other good method that you might suggest.

Comment: @Aditya Kumar: There are different approaches that you can use that will be better than the `O(n^2)` approach. One option is keeping a set of nodes that have been checked in the container, initially empty. Iterate over the container, for each new node check all edges and if any of the referenced nodes is already present in the set the order is invalid. Add this node to the set and continue forward. That approach is `O(V log N)` (`V` being the number of edges, `N` the number of nodes)

Comment: @Aditya Kumar: Now, with deeper knowledge of the code, if you can guarantee that all the edges refer to elements in the same vector, you can use pointer arithmetic to speed up the process: Since the vector stores the elements contiguously, you can compare the pointers, node `a` is before `b` in the vector if `&b - &a > 0`. Using that you can just iterate over the container, and verify that for each edge, the address of the source node is smaller than the address of the destination node. This should be `O( V )` where `V` is the number of vertices.

Comment: @Aditya Kumar: After rereading your comment, I am not sure that you understand the problem. The problem is that you cannot compare the vectors, you need to verify the topological order against the graph, not against a given topological order. Comparing the vector contents will **not** tell you whether your original container was in topological order or not (well, it will a few times, if the order provided by the library coincides with yours). Comparing the two lists in the answer will tell you that they differ, but it won't tell you that **both** are correct.

Comment: i have added an approach which i tried, please have a look at it

Comment: The question is still the same. *What is the problem to resolve?* Do you want to check whether the two vectors have the *same exact* order? (Then make the elements comparable and use `v1 == v2`) Or do you want to know whether the original vector is a valid topological order? In which case you need to forget about comparing the vectors, as that **does not** help you know whether the order is correct or not. Given `{ A, B, C }` and links `{ (A,B), (A,C) }`, the inputs `{ A, B, C }` and `{ A, C, B }` are both valid, but exact comparison with a given order will only yield `true` for one.

Comment: I cannot comment on the specific algorithm, as there are too many unknowns for me: the whole representation of the graph (i.e. `Graph_t`, `Vertex_t`, `Vd_t`) meaning of `depGraph`... you should try to explain the algorithm in pseudocode (i.e. describe the algorithm, not the code) Performing a topological order with a given library and comparing your container with the result of that does not seem a good approach (in general). Verifying a topological order does not require having an example of order, and I still don't see how it might help.

Comment: `It is probably better to write a simple algorithm that will check the order for correctness and reorder if needed.`    was really helpful. i agree my requirements are very specific and explaining them here was not possible. Any way i ended up writing 'a simple algorithm' to solve my problem. Your comments helped me in designing my algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Do I understand your question correctly that you want to test if a list of vertices is already in topological order?

If so, you might do the following:

- Let the list of vertices be `v`.  Now construct a list `r` where `r[i]` gives the index of vertex `i` in `v`, i.e. `v[r[i]] = i`.
- Then loop over all directed edges `(i,j)` and check that `r[i] <= r[j]`.
- If so, the list `v` is already in topological order.

However, this will be just as slow as doing a full topological sort of `v` (both are linear in the number of edges plus number of vertices).  So if your aim is just to have `v` in topological order, just do the sorting.  If you need to keep `v` in the current order if possible, this will be useful.

Comment: your ideas were closer, +1 for that

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` has `operator==` so you can simply `if(v1==v2)`

Edit: this is a sufficient but not neccesary condition.